# Failed to start the cordapp-example (Windows 10)

Tags: corda

Windows 10 platform
Using the notes "https://docs.corda.net/docs/corda-os/3.2/getting-set-up.html" I failed to start the Cordapp Example nodes as documented.
After issuing the command "gradelw deployNodes", I see 7 command windows start. Some show the text "Listening for transport dt_socket at address: nnnn". Some show this plus more output up to "Starting as webserver: localhost:nnnnn", some showed a fuller output with "Cordapp" styled text, and some no output at all.
When I browse with Chrome to "http://localhost:10007/web/example/" I see no rendered page.
Can you hint me as to how to proceed?
I have a fuller doc for this issue, but cannot attach it here.
Many thanks for any thoughtful feedback.
Regards
Dave Harrison

Comment: The link that you shared mentions Corda version as `3.2`; we are currently at version `4.4`, please make sure that you are using the latest documentation. Also update your question with a print screen of your terminal's output; or paste the text in a formatted form (see guidance on formatting [here](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)).

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to https://github.com/corda/samples/tree/release-V4/cordapp-example for the latest version of the cordapp example.

Also the docs for deploying and running the above sample is at: https://docs.corda.net/docs/corda-os/4.4/tutorial-cordapp.html